# How to regex space-separated letters?

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to validate a string that it only contains single letters (restricted to A, B, C) that are separated by one or more spaces, and that there are no more than 3 letters.

Expected result:

```
A: true
A B: true
A B C: true
B C A: true
A B C D: false
A B D: false
AB C: false
```

Probably the regex must contain `A\s*|B\s*|C\s*`, but what else?

Comment: Ought to see \s+ for one or more spaces

Comment: Can they be repeated? Can they come in any order?

Comment: They can come unordered; @Tim: that does catch `A C B A` which it should not.

Comment: I deleted it. I noticed It also matches a space at the end. I didnt notice the three character limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works fine:

```
^[ABC]{1}( [ABC]){0,2}$
```

You match the first character, which should start the line. Then you match between 0 and 2 groups of `[A-Z]` separated by spaces. No whitespaces left or right `(^ $)`

Answer (score 3):

```
[ABC]( +[ABC])?( +[ABC])?
```

or

```
[ABC]( +[ABC]( +[ABC])?)?
```

or

```
[ABC]( +[ABC]){0,2}
```

Comment: This one seems good, but shouldn't it be \s instead of space?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the next:

```
^[ABC]( [ABC]( [ABC])?)?$
```

Comment: This does not match `C B A`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a limited quantifier like this:

```
[ABC](?: +[ABC]){0,2}
```